# The critical value

Tags: probability, statistics

I am facing a little problem is this question. Can somebody please help e here

A sample of 500 drivers was asked whether or not they speed while driving. The following table gives a two-way classification:

[image]

We wish to test whether gender and speeding are related at the 1% significant level.

What is the critical value for the test? Also state the null and alternative hypothesis. I need help in this.

Comment: This is is a chi^2 test right?

Comment: Yes it is Chi test. I found the P-value from an online calculator to b 0.0218. What should I do next please?

Comment: Well 2.18% isn't significant enough so you don't reject the alternative (i.e. that they are related in any way).

Comment: So what will be null and alternative hypothesis for the test? H0: µ = 500 -->null hypothesis H1: µ < 500 -->alternative hypothesis. Is that correct?

Comment: No, it's something along the lines of
$$H_0:p_{male}=p_{female}$$
$$H_a:p_{male}\ne p_{female}$$
Where $p$ is the probability of speeding.

Comment: So what will be the value of Pfemale. Can u help please?

Comment: oh it's not the p-value, it's the probability. Those hypotheses were terribly worded, I guess.

Comment: So can u help me out with the probability please? actually I am little bit dull in it. also m new in it

Comment: I don't remember much of chi^2. Post another question and hopefully people will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I spent yesterday reviewing the chi-squared test.

The table you have right there is the *observed* values. If you recall, the formula for the $X^2$ statistic is:

$$X^2=\frac{\sum (\text{observed - expected})^2}{\text{expected}}$$

So the first thing we want is the expected values. You can use your calculator to find all the expected values. For TI-83, plug in all the values for the males and females in a matrix like so:

\begin{bmatrix}
        222 & 78 \\
        128 & 72
        \end{bmatrix}

Then go to `STAT->X^2-Test...`, change the observed matrix (if you need to, but don't worry about expected), and click calculate. This will give you everything you need - the $X^2$ value, the p-value, and it will place the expected values in the matrix you selected (default `[B]`).

Without the calculator, you'll have to follow these steps. First, the expected value for each cell of the matrix:

$$\text{expected}=\frac{\text{row total} \times \text{column total}}{\text{table total}}$$

The table total is of course $500$. Then the row total and the column total are different for each cell. Just look to the left or to the right of the cell. For example, the expected value for the Male and Speed cell is $\frac{300 \times 350}{500}$. You'll get that all the expected values are:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
210 & 90\\
140 & 60
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now you can perform the Chi-squared test for all of them. A shortcut would be to add the observed values to a list, the expected values to another list, and perform the operation mentioned at the top of this answer and assign it to another list. Get the sum of the list and you'll get that the $X^2$ statistic is:

$$\therefore X^2\approx 5.7143$$

To get the p-value, you'll have to either use a chart or your calculator. Your degrees of freedom is $(r-1)(c-1)$, where $r=$ number of rows, and $c=$ number of columns. In this case, they're both $2$ so our degree of freedom is $(2-1)(2-1)=1$. On your calculator, you can use your `X^2cdf()` function to get it (from $X^2\approx 5.7143$ to $\infty$). You'll get a p-value of:

$$\therefore p\approx1.6827\%$$

Which is not significant at the $1\%$ level.